# How can Visual studio compile angular2 and typescript with @angular paths

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2015 and a asp.net core project and angular2 (rc1) with typescript.

I am having a major issue with Angular2 and the new paths @angular/core for instance.

the problem is that the typescript compiler cant find @angular directive. and i cant find any way to fix this.  so question is how do i make the visual studio compiler understand where to look for the angular files. or is it not even possible to do so?

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router'; // this gives error
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';  // this works


bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,  HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

error message is:
Error   TS2307  Build: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.

The application is working even with these compile errors. since the script files are included from the npmcdn.com repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not having a file directory `./` etc, it is by *default* looking at the `node_modules` folder.

If you have these located elsewhere you need to point to that location.

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '../somewhere-else/@angular/router';
```

If you're trying to use a CDN (which I would highly advise **against** doing), you will still need to let SystemJS or Webpack know about your angular packages that are globally placed on the `window`.

A webpack example:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    '@angular/router': 'angular.router' // This right side might be different
  }
};
```

> I would suggest using `npm` and containing your neccessary files within `node_modules`. This way, when you are doing things like importing specific parts of libraries, it will only grab **those specific portions**. A CDN will include the entire library, and pollute your global window namespace (which is just bad joo-joo)

Comment: i am using npm, but keeps getting these problems i have also tried going back to beta17 and using angular2/... paths but dosent work either maybe something is wrong in my setup.  CDN is used or the html page just so i dont have to host the files.